# GetWindowText vs Process.MainWindowTitle

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I'm trying to obtain process information for the current active application (or window), using .Net/C#.

Currently I'm using

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

To get the current active window.
I understand there's no native way to do this other than use this API function.

From that, I use:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern UInt32 GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out Int32 lpdwProcessId);
```

To get the process name that belongs to that window and then I get further process information.

I also use

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);
```

To get the current Window Text or caption.

Now, using the Process class, I can use 
    MainWindowTitle
to get the main Window title as well.

The thing is, MainWindowTitle and GetWindowText does not return the same information.

For example, let's say the main application opened is "Toad" with a connection and an editor open.
Then with GetWindowText I get:

```
"Toad for Oracle - myConnection - Somequery.sql".
```

and Process.MainWindowTitle returns

```
"myConnection".
```

So, the question is how do I get the exact same text as I get using GetWindowText, but using merely .Net classes?

Edit:
I found out that actually the reason is simply because both functions are not querying the same window handle.
The window handle returned in the GetForegroundWindow, is the number 198982.
And the MainWindowHandle property, which I suppose is the one used in the MainWindowTitle propery is the number 198954.
Using Spy++ I could find and confirm those windows handle captions are the one returned by their corresponding function.

So the "problem", if any, is that the Process class does not correctly identify the most foreground window as the Main Window.

Comment: `GetWindowText`.  Then again you might want to look into _Microsoft UI Automation_ instead of p-invoking about.  Plus it will work with WPF

Comment: Looking at the ref source MainWindowTitle is a simple p/invoke call to GetWindowText - However it's return value cached in a field which is possibly the cause of the discrepancy.

Comment: @AlexK. my main concern about this is to not abuse of p-invoke and keep my .net application on the safe side. But if MainWindowTitle property just wrap a call to the same GetWindowText function, then I'm wasting my time.

Comment: You can see it here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,b2593fc1f1f116b3

Answer (score 0):

`GetForegroundWindow` gives you the active window the user is working in and that might be a owned window or a modal dialog, not necessarily the applications main/root window.

MainWindow is a .NET concept, native win32 does not have such a thing and there can be 0, 1 or multiple "main windows" in an application.

Some Delphi/C++Builder applications have a HWND for the taskbar button and each form is a owned window belonging to this "invisible" window. Other UI frameworks may pull similar stunts that might confuse "main window" detection.

You can use [UI Automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation) to inspect other applications if you don't want to use p-invoke. Start with the foreground window and walk up the tree of owned and child windows...

Comment: "*Some Delphi/C++Builder applications have a HWND for the taskbar button and each form is a owned window belonging to this "invisible" window*" - note that such behavior is not the default for modern D/CB apps running on Vista+. Only legacy apps still do that. Vista changed the way things like Alt-Tab and Taskbar work, so such "stunts" dont interact well with Windows anymore

Comment: @RemyLebeau That is correct but those issues can mostly be fixed with custom thumbnails etc. Either way, interacting with unknown applications means you have to be ready for everything.

Comment: You guys are so right about how old applications behave and yes, Toad is written in Delphi. In his lastest 2018 version it still behave bad. One example is the taskbar icon does not move to the corresponding monitor when working in multimonitor setup. My whole code works fine for everything I have opened in  my current workstation, except for Toad, just for that, it returns a different window caption.